# Handling join operation efficiently

Tags: mysql, join

I have these two tables.

Table 1 with 10 million entries having columns gameid and gamename
Table 2 with few thousand entries having columns userid and gamename. I want to get the corresponding gameid for each user by mapping the gamenames from the two tables.

My query is like this

```
SELECT game.id FROM game RIGHT JOIN player ON game.game_name=player.game_name
```

But it's like taking ages. What could be the efficient way to do it?

Comment: Sorry, bad comment, bad reading tonight... You should have At LEAST have an index on the field you are joining on (from each table)

Comment: @DRapp. I only want the game ids of the games played by the players. So if I have 1000 players, I just need 1000 ids of the games played by the players

Answer (score 2):

If you want the lookup to go quickly, then create an index on `game(game_name, gameid)`.

This should be reasonable, assuming that there are few duplicate names in the `game` table.  If there are, your problem may also be sheer volume of data being returned.

Comment: I am trying to create some index as you said. But creating index is like taking ages. What should I do?

Comment: @user34790 . . . Wait a bit.  You have 10 million rows so it will take some time (perhaps tens of minutes).

Answer (score 2):

Consider using...

```
EXPLAIN SELECT game.id FROM game RIGHT JOIN player ON game.game_name=player.game_name
```

The initial `EXPLAIN` will get MySQL to tell you what it's doing with a good explanation of the output being [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html).

You most likely want some sort of index on both `game.game_name` and `player.game_name`.